# Help with a SQL querying speed and performance issue

Tags: php, sql, performance, logic, pseudocode

I've got a classified listing website for cars which I'm in the process of developing built in PHP. The user enters the details of the car they are looking for using drop down option boxes on the homepage. When they click submit they are taken through to the results page, and this is where I'm having problems.

The way it is set-up at the moment is:

1. The database is queried for any results matching the car they are looking for. The query returns the ID of the car and the Postcode of the advert;
2. Each advert is then checked for the distance between the users postcode and the postcode of the advert. This itself requires a database query to find the coordinates for individual postcodes of each advert and is quite time consuming for what can be in excess of 350 results at times;
3. An if statement is then used to determine if the distance is less than or equal to the distance the user entered on the homepage
4. If the advert is within the allowed distance it's ID is added to an array;
5. The total number of adverts in the array is then calculated and used to determine a variable dependant on the number of adverts and the number of adverts to be displayed on the page;
6. A second query of the advert table is then executed using a `WHERE` statement and the ID's in the array. e.g. `SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE ID=1 AND ID=4 AND ID=23` ........ The total number of ID's used in the query depend on the variable mentioned in point 5. When the user then clicks next page the query is re-run from the position in the array that it was left at and the query is then re-created and executed.

The problem I'm having is that it is taking ages to complete and I was looking for a more resource and time concious way of completing it.

It originally was designed that a query would execute with WHERE clauses for each of the users specific requirements for the car, and then before being output to the page the distance was being checked using an if statement. This caused problems with the page numbering because it was impossible to determine the number of adverts that would match the distance requirements from the adverts returned in the query- hence it is done this way with the distance conditions being satisfied before the full adverts are collected so an exact number of adverts to be displayed is calculated.

Sorry its a little long - hope it makes sense. I haven't included any code because it would make it longer, and its a problem with the logic as opposed to the actual code.

Thanks for any suggestions you are able to make.

Someone has requested the table layout and SQL. Here goes.....

> Advert Table
>
> ID, Make, Model, Colour, Mileage, Engine, Year, Postcode
>
> Postcode Table
>
> ID, Postcode, GridN, GridE, Longitude, Latitude

SQL for first query to get the ID and Postcode

`SELECT ID, Postcode FROM adverts WHERE Make = '$subMake' AND Model = '$subModel'` etc

SQL for the second query to get the advert details using the ID's that match the distance requirements:

```
SELECT Make, Model, Year, Engine, Colour FROM adverts WHERE ID IN(1,2,6,90,112,898)
```

(Sorry if its not syntactically correct, it does work, that SQL is just a rough outline of the many lines of the query strings.)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE ID=1 AND ID=4 AND ID=23` would surely always return 0 rows?  Do you mean `SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE ID IN (1, 4, 23)` instead?

Comment: the very least needed for some answer is the table structure and the SQL you are using...

Comment: Is it not possible to do the distance calculation in your SQL statement and then filter before returning?  This would be a lot faster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest optimization would be query the postcode table and store the Grid references in the adverts table -- when you are inserting the advert row.

This would drastically reduce the number of accesses to the post code table.

You could also reduce the number of calculations by some simple filtering on the advert table as follows.

Get the Users GridN and GridE values from the post code table.
Calculate minN as GridN - maxDistance , maxN as GridN + maxDistance, minE as GridE - maxDistance, and maxE as GridE + Maxdistance.

You can then query on the advert table like so:

```
SELECT * FROM ADVERTS WHERE GridN between (minN,maxN) and GridE Between(minE,maxE);
```

To further speed this up you can add indexes to GridN and GridE.

Once you have selected the rows you can calculate the "real" distance and reject the few rows that fall outside the limit.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, sounds like it's exactly what I need - I'm going to implement it later today. What I'm having trouble getting my head around is how exactly it calculates the distance though. I was used to calculating it using trigonometry. How does this way work? Thanks

Comment: You are not really calculating the distnce, you are selecting a "square" of geography which completely contains the "circle" which defines the x miles from your client. There will be points towards the corners of the square which fall outside the circle. I.E. If your user selected ads within 10 miles this query will still select an add placed 9.9 miles north and 9.9 miles East of your client which is actually a distance of 14 miles -- you need to do a further trigonometric calculation to reject these outliers. However you have efficiently eliminated 99% of the adverts using simple comparison!

Comment: With the distance that is used to calculate the min and max distances, unless I use a figure above 3000 no results are returned, and then as I increase the distance more are displayed. Do I have to change the unit the distance is measure in to something else? Apart from that it has sped the whole process up x10. Thanks!!

Comment: You are gonna have to read the docs! No idea what units the GridX numbers come in -- depends on your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Amend the query so that it includes the distance between the postcodes and is restricted to those adverts within the specified distance range.

Comment: Hi @mark The problem with doing that is that the distance isn't in any table so can't be queried. The distance is worked out on a per-user basis on the page with a function that takes in the two postcodes (advert postcode and user postcode) and then returns a distance which is then checked.

Comment: Hi @Max. Can the function to determine distance be created within the database as a user-defined function?

Comment: The problem here is you need to do the primary school Pythagoras calculation "square root of the sum of x squared and y squared"  on every row. The square root calculation is whats eating up the time.

Comment: @James: no, that's the least of the problems here. Data access time is a much greater concern, particularly when each result has to be retrieved individually.

Comment: Yes but its not possible to index the result of such an ephemeral calculation so all rows in the table need to be accessed and the calculation applied to every candidate row. You don't know the users postcode or the distance requested until just before each  query is run.

Comment: The problem with Max's current approach is that he is retrieving everything in the query, and then filtering in PHP. He should see significant performance advantages by restricting the results returned to those within the distance, which would also make the second query redundant. Adding restrictions and indexes on the Grid values, as suggested in your answer, could further speed up the query when querying from large tables.

Comment: Another possible alternative would be to query the postcodes database to locate those post codes within "x miles/klicks" than select only those adds which match the postcodes. Still means performing the expensive distance  = square root easting squared plus northing squared on every post code row. While calculations usually don't normally matter that much "square root" eats up significant amounts of cpu.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your distance function into a view with all possible combinations of postcodes, then you can join on that within your queries rather than hitting the function, or you can calculate the latitudes and longitudes that are 50km from your user's post code

Further to that if you provide fixed options (most of these websites offer 5, 10, 25, 50, 100 as the distance options only) then you can pre-compute these distance calculations and to go even further you could do the extra check and map each postcode to all the ones nearby if you really wanted, you would only need to calculate it 5 times (5 distances) for each post code, and you could exclude the results from the previous value, such that you exclude 5km from the 10km query because you just look for distance <= 10km.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database maybe use something like PostGIS?

Setup a column in the Adverts table for a LonLat datatype and then run the built-in functions such as ST_DWithin to find all adverts with a LonLat within a specified distance from the target record.

Just to point out another issue that I find with using a static postcode database is that they quickly go out of date (especially for new builds). You might also want to use something like Mapstraction to return a geocoded result from Google / Yahoo etc and save that LonLat instead - although you might have to have more error checking on the postcode input and restrict your returned results to exact matches.